# "ping 10.26.14.16" is successful. "nmap -p 5016 10.26.14.16" is unsuccessful. Why?

Tags: linux, iptables, nat, router

```
192.168.1.*/27
      
      :
      |
      +---  FW
      |
      +---  [192.168.1.133]  A 
      |
      +---  [192.168.1.140]  B
      |
      :
```

A = linux machine as a router [192.168.1.133/27]
B = linux machine [192.168.1.140/27]

A and B are in the same network 192.168.1.127/27. A doesn't have any additional interfaces.

Note:

1. From B, `ping 10.26.14.26`  is successful, but `nmap -p 5016 10.26.14.26` says

   ```
   1 Host is UP but Port/TCP=5016/tcp filtered, service=unknown.
   ```
2. A is configured as a linux router.

   ```
   net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
   ```

My Requirement:  `nmap -p 5016 10.26.14.26` should be successful.

I want to bypass FW policy for B. B is in same lan with A. FW has policy to A.

Comment: "A is a router" and "A has a single IP address" don't mix. A router has (at least) two LAN interfaces. It's also totally unclear which machine `10.26.14.26` is. Please edit your question, and describe your setup more completely.

Comment: @dirkit A and B are in the same network 192.168.1.127/27. From A, I can "nmap -p 5016 10.26.14.16" . But from B, "nmap -p 5016 10.26.14.16" is unsuccessful . In addition, from B, "ping 10.26.14.16" is successful. I have used A has a linux router.

Comment: So A and B are both connected to FW? If yes, please update the question. You still haven't said what `10.26.24.16` is ... (it's in the private range, so it ought to be somewhere in your LAN). If it works on A, but not on B, the first thing to do is to check firewall settings on B (unless there's something special about 10.26.14.16, which requires a special setup on A to make it work).

Comment: @dirkt I want to bypass FW policy for B. B is in same lan with A. FW has policy to A.

Comment: Please edit your question and add all this information ... because we **cannot** guess it. And your solution is not going to work, you need a different approach.

Comment: @dirkt   I am "Unable to connect to TEST server 10.26.14.16:5016" from B.  Why ? However, I can ping 10.26.14.16 from B. A is configured as linux as a router.

Answer (score 0):

> I am "Unable to connect to TEST server 10.26.14.16:5016" from B. Why ? A is configured as linux as a router.

1. Unless you tell B to use A as gateway, you can "configure A as a router" all day long, it will do exactly nothing.
2. Even if you do (1), ICMP REDIRECT messages will tell B to directly connect to the firewall.
3. Even if A and B were not in the same segment, just routing from B via A would still trigger the settings for B in the firewall (or not trigger the settings for A, we don't know the exact setup of the FW).

TL;DR: What you are trying to do won't work this way.

If you can control A, there are multiple ways to have B "disguise" as A. Since you didn't tell us what you want to achieve (just connect to port 5016 on 10.26.14.26, where ever it is? Something else?), and to what degree you can do something on A (have different rules for A and B in the firewall if you completely control A doesn't make sense), we can't tell you the best way.

And maybe you **shouldn't** try to go around the firewall rules for B, they might be there for a reason (which again you didn't tell us).

Comment: A's IP is 192.168.1.133/27 and B's IP is  192.168.1.140./27. A can reach 10.26.14.16:5016. A is configured as a router using "net.ipv4.ip_forward=1".  B is configured to use gateway 192.168.1.133[A] for destination 10.26.14.16 by command "iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d 10.26.14.16 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.133". The problem is from B, I can ping 10.26.14.16 but I cannot "nc -vz 10.26.14.16 5016". In other words, B can reach 10.26.14.16 but it cannot reach 10.26.14.16:5016? What's mistake in my configuration? What things I need to add in configuration to make B reach 10.26.14.16:5016?